# Generate scatter graph in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5, scatter-plot

I am exporting the table data to excel and trying to generate a scatter graph for it.

The code for generating is as follows,

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
For i = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount - 1
   For j = 0 To DataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1
       xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
       DataGridView2(j, i).Value.ToString()
   Next
Next
'create chart
Dim chartPage As Excel.Chart
Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
Dim chartRange As Excel.Range
xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
myChart = xlCharts.Add(180, 80, 300, 250)
chartPage = myChart.Chart

With chartPage
   chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("B2", "C16")
   .SetSourceData(chartRange)
   'set how you want to draw chart i.e column wise or row wise
   .PlotBy = Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns
   'set data labels for bars
   .ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowNone)
   'set legend to be displayed or not
   .HasLegend = True
   'set legend location
   .Legend.Position = Excel.XlLegendPosition.xlLegendPositionRight
   'select chart type
   .ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatter
   'chart title
   .HasTitle = True
   .ChartTitle.Text = "XY Scatter Chart"
   'set titles for Axis values and categories
   Dim xlAxisCategory, xlAxisValue As Excel.Axes
   xlAxisCategory = CType(chartPage.Axes(,                           
   _Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary), Excel.Axes)
   xlAxisCategory.Item(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory).HasTitle = True
   xlAxisCategory.Item(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory)
      .AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Title 1"
   xlAxisValue = CType(chartPage.Axes(, _Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary),  
      Excel.Axes)
   xlAxisValue.Item(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).HasTitle = True
   xlAxisValue.Item(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).AxisTitle.Characters.Text 
      = "Velocity"
End With
xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\vbexcel.xlsx")
xlWorkBook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()

releaseObject(xlApp)
releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
```

and the output after generating it I get like below,

[image: Graph based on above code]

but the actual graph appears to be like this If I generate graph manually in the excel

[image: Expected Graph when generated manually in excel]

I am using Visual Studio 13 and Framework 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually create the `Series` object and supply it with `XValues` and `Values` properties accordingly.  This replaces the call to `SetSourceData`.

Here is some rough C# code that works.  I apologize for not using VB.NET.  The key step is to use the `NewSeries` method on the `SeriesCollection` object to get an empty series to add data to.  [Here is the MS support for `NewSeries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.seriescollection.newseries.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

```
private void CreateChartAddSeries()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl_app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xl_app.Visible = true;

    Workbook wkbk = xl_app.Workbooks.Add();
    Worksheet wksht = wkbk.Worksheets[1];

    wksht.get_Range("A1:A10").Formula = "=RAND()";
    wksht.get_Range("B1:B10").Formula = "=RAND()";

    ChartObjects cht_objs = wksht.ChartObjects();
    ChartObject cht_obj = cht_objs.Add(100, 0, 300, 300);

    Chart cht = cht_obj.Chart;
    cht.ChartType = XlChartType.xlXYScatter;

    SeriesCollection sc = cht.SeriesCollection();

    Series ser = sc.NewSeries();
    ser.Values = wksht.get_Range("B1:B10");
    ser.XValues = wksht.get_Range("A1:A10");

}
```

**Results**

[image: result of C# code]

Comment: do you have an idea how to display the trendline and trendline equation?

Comment: Check out the [docs for Chart.Trendlines.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.trendlines.add.aspx).  It will allow you to add a trendline and show whatever details you want.

Comment: I have a doubt will this program run without Microsoft Office application?

Comment: It needs the computer to have Office.  This is to use the Interop libraries and the underlying Excel application.